# PHP Get recurring week from specific start date

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm looking into trying to set up and array that will look something like this:

```
$dates = array(
    [0] => "07/11/2013",
    [1] => "14/11/2013",
    [2] => "21/11/2013",
    [3] => "28/11/2013",
    [4] => "05/12/2013",
    [5] => "12/12/2013");
```

I'm willing to use this, but as I want this to reoccur again next year I'd prefer to have PHP do this and enter it into an array for me. I know how to limit it to a specific amount that I want, but I don't know how to add a week onto the current date or specific date if I wanted to start `08/11/2013` for example.

I've had a quick look and I can't seem to find anything that does this.

I just need a script to add a week to the current date, at the moment this is every Thursday, and then add that to the array.

My only problem is I'm not sure how to specify a date, and then add a week every time. I assume a `for` loop would be best here.

Comment: How are you doing it now? Have a look at `date` and `strtotime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class.  DateInterval and DatePeriod classes were introduced in PHP 5.3.0, so the below solution works for only PHP >= 5.3.0:

```
$start = new DateTime('2013-11-07');
$end = new DateTime('2013-12-31');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');  // one week

$p = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($p as $w) {
    $weeks[] = $w->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/62585)

As Glavic notes in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840912/php-get-recurring-week-from-specific-start-date/19841137#comment29529922_19841137), this can also be done in previous versions of PHP using the [`modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method:

```
$start = new DateTime('2013-11-07');
$end = new DateTime('2013-12-31');

$weeks = array();
while ($start < $end) {
    $weeks[] = $start->format('d-m-Y');
    $start->modify('+1 week');
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/64507)

Comment: Though a good solution, this only works php 5.4 and up :) Not very uncommon, but might result in disapointment if lower versions :)

Comment: @Martijn: Yeah, but DateTime is the best. I added an explanation at the top. Cheers :)

Comment: I had seen some examples using the answer below, however, I'm running 5.4.7 at the moment and this suited my needs perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Martijn, AmalMurali: DateInterval and DatePeriod classes were introduced in PHP 5.3.0; don't know where you found that it only works on >=5.4.0? This code can be modified, so it can run on PHP >= 5.2.0, like [this](http://3v4l.org/HZmBE).

Answer (score 1):

[strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) does what you need

```
 $nextWeek = strtotime('08/11/2013 + 1 week');
```

If you need that 8 times, loop it 8 times. You can make a function with `$start` and `$numWeek` to return an array with `$numWeeks`+1 values (the start added)

```
function createDateList($start, $numWeeks){
    $dates = array($start);// add first date
    // create a loop with $numWeeks illiterations:
    for($i=1;$<=$numWeeks; $i++){
        // Add the weeks, take the first value and add $i weeks to it
        $time = strtotime($dates[0].' + '.$i.' week'); // get epoch value
        $dates[] = date("d/M/Y", $time); // set to prefered date format
        
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime('+1 week', $unixTimestamp)` for this:

```
<?php
    $startDate = '2013-11-07';
    $endDate = '2013-12-31';

    $startDateUnix = strtotime($startDate);
    $endDateUnix = strtotime($endDate);

    $dates = array();

    while ($startDateUnix < $endDateUnix) {
        $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', $startDateUnix);
        $startDateUnix = strtotime('+1 week', $startDateUnix);
    }

    print_r($dates);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-11-07
    [1] => 2013-11-14
    [2] => 2013-11-21
    [3] => 2013-11-28
    [4] => 2013-12-05
    [5] => 2013-12-12
    [6] => 2013-12-19
    [7] => 2013-12-26
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/VOxNE3if)

(format the `date()` call in any way you want to get the format you want).

Answer (score -1):

would the `strtotime()` function work here?

```
$nextweek = strtotime('thursday next week');
$date = date('d/m/Y', $nextweek);
```

To create a 5 element array containing today (or this thursday) and the next 4:

```
for ($a = 0; $a < 5; $a++)
{
  $thur = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("thursday this week + $a weeks"));
  $dates[] = $thur;
}
```

Comment: But how are you doing this for a recurring amount of weeks?