# Show date ranges for each month

Tags: php, date

I am trying to display a date range for each month.

For example,

November 2013 -- 2013-11-01 - 2013-11-30 //for month Nov

December 2013 -- 2013-12-01 - 2013-12-31 //for month Dec

January 2013 -- 2014-01-01 - 2014-01-31 //for month jan 2014

so on till dec 2014

PHP code:

```
$currentmonth = date('n');
$monthstoloop = $currentmonth + 13;

for ($m=$currentmonth; $m<=$monthstoloop; $m++) {
$month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));
$year = date('Y', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));
echo $month."  ".$year;
}
```

I am not finding a way to display the month range just beside the year.Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use format parameter `t` to get last day of the month:

```
$start = new DateTime('2013-10-01');
$end = new DateTime('2014-05-01');

while ($start < $end) {
    echo $start->format('M Y = Y-m-d - Y-m-t'), "\n";
    $start->modify('+1 month');
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/64491).

---

Updated your example:

```
$currentmonth = date('n');
$monthstoloop = $currentmonth + 13;
for ($m=$currentmonth; $m<=$monthstoloop; $m++) {
    $time = mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,date('Y'));
    echo date('F Y = Y-m-d - Y-m-t', $time), "\n";
}
```

Comment: `+1` for actually answering the question :)

Comment: PrithvirajMitra: np, glad I can help. @AmalMurali: I see we think alike, we answered with same answer ;)

Comment: @Glavić: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840912/php-get-recurring-week-from-specific-start-date/19841137#comment29529922_19841137) is probably related :P

Answer (score 1):

It's easier with DateTime class:

```
$start = new DateTime('2013-11-01');
$end = new DateTime('2014-12-01');

while ($start <= $end) {
    echo $start->format('F Y -- Y-m-d - Y-m-t').'<br/>';
    $start->modify('+1 month');
}
```

Output:

```
November 2013 -- 2013-11-01 - 2013-11-30
December 2013 -- 2013-12-01 - 2013-12-31
January 2014 -- 2014-01-01 - 2014-01-31
February 2014 -- 2014-02-01 - 2014-02-28
March 2014 -- 2014-03-01 - 2014-03-31
April 2014 -- 2014-04-01 - 2014-04-30
May 2014 -- 2014-05-01 - 2014-05-31
June 2014 -- 2014-06-01 - 2014-06-30
July 2014 -- 2014-07-01 - 2014-07-31
August 2014 -- 2014-08-01 - 2014-08-31
September 2014 -- 2014-09-01 - 2014-09-30
October 2014 -- 2014-10-01 - 2014-10-31
November 2014 -- 2014-11-01 - 2014-11-30
December 2014 -- 2014-12-01 - 2014-12-31
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/64497)

Comment: Nice one Amal but for some reason I can't use datetime class. Many thanks for your effort.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra: Bummer. Anyway, good luck with your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are only 12 months in a year.

Why not hard code them and have the fiddle with February

Seems an easy and quick solution